# How to reach elements in a std::set two by two in C++

Tags: c++, stdvector, c++98, stdset

I have a list of integers.(Currently stored in a std::vector but to increase efficieny, I need to convert it to set. But in current version, I use it as following: (I'm using c++98 not c++11)

```
int res=0;
vector<vector<int> >costMatrix;
vector<int>partialSolution;
    for(int i =0;i<partialSolution.size()-1;i++){
        res+=costMatrix[partialSolution.get(i)][partialSolution.get(i+1)];
    }
```

So, I need to do the same thing with the set data structure. But I dont know how to get two elements from the set at a time. I can get the `partialSolution.get(i)` with the code below but I could not get the `partialSolution.get(i+1)`. Is there anyone to help me to modify the code below?

```
 // this time set<int> partialSolution
    int res=0;
    std::set<int>::iterator it;
    for (it = partialSolution.begin(); it != partialSolution.end(); ++it)
{
    res+=costMatrix[*it][]; 
}
```

Comment: "Currently stored in a `std::vector` but to increase efficiency, I need to convert it to `std:;set`" - that seems highly unlikely to improve performance, `std::set` is very cache-unfriendly.

Comment: In somewhere else in my code, I'm searching whether my vector contains a specific number or not. Actually I have to change that part. But to change it I have to change the part I mentioned above too. @BoBTFish

Comment: are the integers sorted in `partialSolution`?

Comment: If you expect the same behaviour from your `set` as your `vector`, I must assume your `vector` is sorted. Therefore, you may use [`std::lower_bound`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/lower_bound) to efficiently find an existing element (or even [`std::binary_search`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/binary_search) if you only need to know it exists, not access it).

Comment: Have you tried `costMatrix[*it][*(std::next(it))]`?

Comment: @jpo38 when it points the last element isn't it cause an error ?

Comment: @jpo38 that's already c++11

Comment: Sure, but you can iterate to std::prev(partialSolution.end())

Comment: @BoBTFish rather than judging my aim, please help my *real* question if you can.

Comment: @zwlayer I'm trying to establish if this is an [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/242291). When the question is "How can I shoot myself in the foot?", the only correct answer is "Don't!"

Comment: You should rather listen to what he's saying. There's a good chance `vector` will outperform your `set` attempts...

Comment: @KarolyHorvath then let me try both and decide to which of them is better for me.

Comment: `std::set` is `O(log n)` inserts and indexing. `std::vector` is amortized `O(1)` inserts and indexing. Can't think of why you'd want a `std::set` for this task.

Answer (score 2):

This could work (iterating from `begin()` to `end()-1` and using `std::next` or `++` to get item next to current one).

In C++11:

```
for (it = partialSolution.begin(); it != std::prev(partialSolution.end()); ++it)
{
    res+=costMatrix[*it][*(std::next(it))]; 
}
```

In C++98:

```
std::set<int>::iterator last = partialSolution.end();
--last;
for (it = partialSolution.begin(); it != last; ++it)
{
    // not optimal but I'm trying to make it easy to understand...
    std::set<int>::iterator next = it;
    ++next;
    res+=costMatrix[*it][*next]; 
}
```

Comment: it is c++11, OP asked for c++98

Comment: I think the C++11 could be better with `std:accumulate`, but maybe not.

Comment: @jpo38 do you know how could I represent this one also using a set? `for(int i=1;i<partialSolution.size()-1;i++){
        answer+=costMatrix[partialSolution[i-1]][partialSolution[i]];
    }`

Comment: The same way, but just do `std::set<int>::iterator prev = it; --prev;` and then do `answer+=costMatrix[partialSolution[*prev]][partialSolution[*it]];`. Loop has to start as `++begin()`.

Comment: @jpo38 couldnt figure out, if possible could you write it as an edit ?

Comment: @zwlayer You should accept this answer and post a separate question. My answer would not make sense as this question is not part of the original post...